# Save customer in the background on django forms

Tags: python, django, forms

Hi I am trying to automatically save the customer on post without having to list it in the forms. It currently shows the drop down and saves correctly but if I remove customer from forms.py it doesn't save anymore.
views.py

```
  @login_required(login_url='login')
  def createInfringer(request):

     customer=request.user.customer

     form = InfringerForm(customer=customer)
     if request.method == 'POST':
  
        form = InfringerForm(customer, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
     
        form.save()
     return redirect('infringer-list')
  context ={'form': form}
  return render (request, 'base/infringement_form.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
   class InfringerForm(ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, customer, *args, **kwargs):
   super(InfringerForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(name=customer)
   self.fields['status'].queryset = Status.objects.filter(customer=customer)
   class Meta:
    model = Infringer
    fields = ['name', 'brand_name','status','customer']
```

UPDATE
suggestion below was added but it still doesn't save customer.

Comment: Hi, @Farid can you please update the code of the views.py to include tabs in the correct places (like you have it in your code), it will be easier to understand :)

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Refer to this question for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480931/save-fk-on-post-in-django#74481797

Comment: Refer to this link for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480931/save-fk-on-post-in-django#74481797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forms.py

> ```
> class InfringerForm(ModelForm):    
>  class Meta:
>    model = Infringer
>    fields = ['name', 'brand_name', 'status']  
>
>   def __init__(self, customer, *args, **kwargs):
>     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>     self.customer = customer
>     self.fields['status'].queryset = Status.objects.filter(customer=customer)
>
>   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>     self.instance.customer = self.customer
>     return super().save( *args, **kwargs)
> ```

views.py

> ```
> @login_required(login_url='login') def createInfringer(request):
> customer = request.user.customer
> form = InfringerForm(customer=customer)
> if request.method == 'POST':
>     form = InfringerForm(customer, request.POST, request.FILES)
>     if form.is_valid():   
>         saved_instance = form.save()
>         print (f'customer in views.py is {customer}')
>         print (f'Successfully saved the infringer in views.py with its customer {saved_instance.customer}')
>         return redirect('infringer-list')
>
> return render (request, 'base/infringement_form.html', {'form': form})
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you'd like to save the customer in your model but do not wish to show the customer field on your form as the customer is the logged-in user.  If that assumption is correct, you need to first remove the customer field from your form fields and its `__init__` method. Then, you'd need to pass the customer to your save method during the post request as your model probably requires that field:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createInfringer(request):
    customer=request.user.customer
    form = InfringerForm(customer=customer)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InfringerForm(customer, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():   
            saved_instance = form.save(customer)
            print (f'Successfully saved the infringer with its customer {saved_instance.customer}')  ## Insert this and see what it says

        return redirect('infringer-list')
    
    context ={'form': form}
    return render (request, 'base/infringement_form.html', context)

class InfringerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Infringer
       # fields = ['name', 'brand_name','status','customer']
       fields = ['name', 'brand_name','status']  # Notice the above commented line. Also, Add this instead
    
    def __init__(self, customer, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InfringerForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(name=customer)
        self.fields['status'].queryset = Status.objects.filter(customer=customer)
    
    def save(self, customer, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(InfringerForm, self).save( *args, **kwargs) 
        if customer:
            print (f'customer is {customer}')
            self.customer = customer
        
        instance.save()
        print (f'instance was saved with the customer {instance.customer}')
        return instance
```

I have not tested the above code, but it should work

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately its saving the record with an empty customer field.

Comment: put a print statement in the save method and find out if you have a customer object or not

Comment: added print (customer) after form.save(customer) . It does print the customer in terminal so I am puzzled with its not saving it.

Comment: also added it to after instance.save() in forms.py It also prints the customer correctly.

Comment: update your question with the print statements you've added

Comment: Any further suggestions? I am stuck.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some print statements.  Can you insert your print statements where I've shown and let me know what you see?

Comment: Appreciate the help. Output. customer is ABC
instance was saved with the customer None
Successfully saved the infringer with its customer None

Comment: I noticed that the print output is the customer name not the ID. Perhaps thats the issue.  Don't we need to save the customer ID which should be 1.

Comment: Looks like you are not passing the customer object in this line: ```saved_instance = form.save(customer)``` You need to make sure that ```customer=request.user.customer``` returns a customer object and not a string

Comment: added customer=request.user.customer.id after if request. method =='POST'

Comment: PRINT RESULTS:  customer in forms.py is 1 /  forms.py instance was saved with the customer None / customer in views.py is 1 Successfully saved the infringer in views.py with its customer None . Still doesnt save